# Magento 2 And Akeneo PIM

Tags: magento2

> How can I create custom Magento 2 and Akeneo connector to perform both import and export of products?

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://marketplace.akeneo.com/extension/akeneo-connector-magento-2-community-edition It is officially made by the developers of Akeneo.

Comment: Yes thats what i am using it only has functionality to import data from akeneo to magento2 but i want to send data from magento 2 to akeneo.